# Prepare age wise report of members in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm storing a list of members in firestore, along with their birthdates, where each member is a document. Also I'm precalculating the age wise report of members(eg: count of 21-30 agegroup) using firebase functions onWrite trigger. How do I update the report when members age increases. Is there a better architecture for this?

Comment: You could write a cloud function that runs every year and updates the age wise report of every user.

Comment: @YouriLieverdink In that case, report won't be accurate except the day the report is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd typically store the count per birth date, instead of (or in addition to) storing the ages. That way you don't have any action to take on the user's birth date, you merely have to rerun the tally each time.

To limit the number of documents you have to read for this tally, you can store all birth dates and their counts in a single document, or (if there are too many to fit in a single document) store them in multiple documents (referred to as shards) for example by year/decade. To then determine the total, you need to read all shards, but that will be a limited number of documents, no matter how many users/birthdays there are.